# Simulating keboard text input

Tags: linux, python, virtual-keyboard

Is there such a program which acts like [this site](http://hackertyper.com/), but for selected window on my computer (and gets input from some text file)?

Or maybe can you give some advices about how to write such a program in python?

P.S.: it is desirable for the arch linux, but I'll take any variants

Comment: Please explain which features of "this site" you need.

Comment: @SteveBarnes, press any keys on keyboard, and write text from some file to focused window

Answer (score 1):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) & more recently [SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/) are java applications that can simulate key presses and mouse clicks on any screen, start applications, find the buttons to press, etc. - Script-able in python, RobotFramework, Java & Ruby Script.

They can also assess the results of the programmed actions.

- Price: Free gratis
- Licence: MIT Open Source
- Platform: Windows, Linux & OS-X desktop machines.